# Unable to upload data from android studio to firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My dependencies list are

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

    // Displaying images
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.8.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
}
```

I also connected to the firebase and created Real Time database.
I also set the firebase authentication rule to true

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true
      
    }
  }
}
```

In the MainActivity first i declared 2 variables

```
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
```

and then in OnCreate method I posted this

```
mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
```

After that i called database reference to set string value on the database.

```
 FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new FriendlyMessage(mMessageEditText.getText().toString(), mUsername, null);
                String data=friendlyMessage.getText();
                mMessagesDatabaseReference.setValue(data);
```

This is my FriendlyMessage.java class

```
package com.google.firebase.udacity.friendlychat;

public class FriendlyMessage {

    private String text;
    private String name;
    private String photoUrl;

    public FriendlyMessage() {
    }

    public FriendlyMessage(String text, String name, String photoUrl) {
        this.text = text;
        this.name = name;
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhotoUrl() {
        return photoUrl;
    }

    public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
        this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    }
}
```

But every time firebase is showing this thing

[image: This is my Firebase Realtime database]

please someone help me

Comment: Try migrating completely to androidx

Comment: @ Muhammad Junaid Khalid still facing the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your security rules allow anyone to write any data they want under the `/Users` node in the database. But your code is trying to write directly under the root, where nobody has been granted any permission.

You most likely were looking to allow all read and writes at the root of your database, which can be done with:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

After you've verified that this works, I highly recommend studying the documentation on [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules) to learn how (and why) to write rules that match your exact needs.

Answer (score 0):

where is your root reference without reference how to store data in real time database

please read these doc carefully - https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

and see also these - http://prntscr.com/113qtu5

in your code structure where these kind of code